# Query current and future events, ordered by begin date

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, advanced-custom-fields, date

Using the Custom Post Type UI extension, I've created a 'Event' custom post-type, which fields are populated using custom fields (created with the extension Advanced Custom Fields) such as 'date-debut' and 'date-fin'.

On an archive page dedicated to this post-type, I'm trying to display the 10 next (current or future) events, ordered chronologically by beginning date.

The sorting part seems to be OK by itself; but it doesn't work anymore when I add the tests on dates, and anyway those don't work either.

Here is my code:

```
        $current_date = date('ymd');
        $my_query = new WP_Query( array ( 
        'post_type'         => 'mna_event',
        'posts_per_page'    => 10,
        'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key'          => 'date_debut',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'meta_query'        => array (
            'relation'      => 'OR',
            array (
                'key'       => 'date_debut',
                'value'     => $current_date,
                'compare'   => '>='
                ),
            array (
                'key'       => 'date_fin',
                'value'     => $current_date,
                'compare'   => '>='
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Advice on the matter would be very much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What's the problem ?

Comment: 1) Past events are still returned in the loop.
2) The events are no longer sorted by beginning date when I try to add the filter.

Comment: You are asking for `>=` your finish date. That doesn't look right.

Comment: Try `type` key for `meta_query` with `DATE` or `DATETIME`. Check the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) BTW what is the format of date in the meta value?

Comment: **(1)** you don't need to meta query both 'date_debut' and 'date_fin': query for posts with `'date_fin' >= $current_date` you'll get all current and future events, without querying for 'date_debut' your query became simpler and so better performant. **(2)** Second issue is the way you are saving date, what format are you using? If you are storing date in mysql datetime format `Y-m-d H:i:s` set meta_query type to `DATETIME` (how @Chittaranjan suggests) if you are storing date in other formats, you have to change meta_query type accordingly e.g. for timestamps you have to set type to `NUMERIC`

Comment: **(1)** I did test on both `date_debut` and `date_fin` because `date_fin` wasn't required (for events during less than one day, but I just changed this in order to make things simpler), so I was looking for `date_debut` >= today (future event) OR `date_fin` >= today (current event).
**(2)** According to the ACF plugin settings, dates are stored as`yymmdd` (jQuery format), and from what is said here [link](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to/orde-posts-by-custom-fields/) I thing they are numeric. I tried several meta_query types and none of them got the expecting result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of the `OR` relation on `meta_query` and the way WordPress generates the actual query string. You need to leave out the `meta_key` and `orderby` from the query args and hook into the `posts_clauses` filter to modify the `where` and `orderby` pieces of the query:

```
function wpse_130954_orderby_fix($pieces){
    global $wpdb;
    $pieces['where']  .= " AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'date_debut'";
    $pieces['orderby']  = "$wpdb->postmeta.meta_value ASC";
    return $pieces;
}
```

Add the filter before setting up your WP_Query object and then make sure to remove it after running your query to not affect other queries:

```
add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'wpse_130954_orderby_fix', 20, 1 );
$current_date = date_i18n('Y-m-d');
$my_query = new WP_Query( array ( 
    'post_type'         => 'mna_event',
    'posts_per_page'    => 10,
    'meta_query'        => array (
        'relation'      => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'       => 'date_debut',
            'value'     => $current_date,
            'compare'   => '>=',
            'type'      => 'DATE'
            ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'date_fin',
            'value'     => $current_date,
            'compare'   => '>=',
            'type'   => 'DATE'
            )
        )
    )
);

$result = $my_query->posts;

remove_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'wpse_130954_orderby_fix', 20 );
```

**UPDATE:** Use `yy-mm-dd` format for your date fields on ACF settings. (`yy-mm-dd` in JS/ACF == `Y-m-d` in PHP/MySQL datetime format) I have updated the code above for this format. (updated `$current_date` format and added `'type' => 'DATE'` in `meta_query`)

Comment: I had to get rid of the `public` as it provoked an error. But after that, the result hasn't really improved: I still get events whose `date_fin` is prior today.

Comment: @tosca Did you remove `meta_key`, `order` and `orderby` from your query args? Also see my updated answer above for proper mysql date format.

Comment: I delete my own code and made a copy/paste of yours while replacing `'Y-m-d'` by `'ymd'` as I saw it was coded `yyyymmdd` in the database.
I hadn't seen your update yet, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @tosca Aah, here is the issue: with your original date format (`yymmdd` in ACF) you need to use `Ymd` in php (with capital `Y`) NOT `ymd`. ACF uses jQuery UI Datepicker and `yy` in JQUI Datepicker means 4 digit year which in php is a single capital `Y`. Lowercase `y` in php is two digit year, so `date('ymd')` will be always a numeric value smaller than dates stored for your events and that's why you get all events.

Comment: Great! Thanks to you, it works now. 
I just have to decide on date format as the display is now `yyyy-mm-dd`.